# Logic circuit to limit motor travel based on a sensor 0/1

Tags: digital-logic

I would like to create a very basic 5v logic circuit to control a motor's movement. The control should follow these rules:

- Allow the motor to move in one direction until the a current sensor detects that the motor is drawing too much current.
- Once the motor is stopped (because it reached the current sensor limit) do not allow the motor to continue moving in that direction, even after the current sensor reports acceptable current limit.
- Wait in until a signal arrives that says to drive the motor in the opposite direction. This signal will also reset the opposite direction's sensor limit latch.

I'm using a [BA6286](http://www.vetco.net/datasheets/VUPN6445/ba6286.pdf) which is a basic H-Gate for 12vdc motors and this works as expected. I'm also using a circuit which correctly detects the over current limit and gives me a logic 1 when the current is at an acceptable level, or a logic 0 when the motor draws too much current.

My question about setting up a latch to store the sensor bit that says you can no longer travel in this direction, and getting this latch to be reset when the motor goes in the other direction.

I would prefer to do this in logic, instead of a full up controller chip.

[image]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29

Comment: Yep, those are logic gates but what I'm not clear on which is the best to use, or how to implement one to satisfy my criteria.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: Yep, this is a finate state machine request, but what I'm not clear on is how to implement one with basic logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this using two latches some nor gates and several and gates. I'm sure it's not perfect, but it's the best I could do.